# Зашифрованый текст JS cfemail

Tags: javascript, html, шифрование

Всем привет, на сайте есть такая запись:

```
<p id="u4272-10">Служба поддержки: <a href="cdn-cgi/l/email-protection.html" class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="a3cacdc5cc8ed5c0c5d3cde3cacdc1ccdb8dd1d6">[email&#160;protected]</a></p>
```

Интересует то что после cfemail, мне нужно также вписать только свою почту. Кто знает, пожалуеста скажите как мне так же свою посту зашифровать.

Если нужно больше информации по теме, с радостью отвечу.

Как я понял это Cloudflare шифрование.

Comment: https://usamaejaz.com/cloudflare-email-decoding/

Comment: Yaant, Ну не совсем то, я имел ввиду как зашифровать